# How do you say "what is like to be xx"

Tags: grammar

Eg: "What is it like for T-san to be jealous?"

Is it ヤキモチ焼きのTさんはどうですか？

Thank you!

Comment: ↓ So.. T-san is not the subject of "to be jealous"... (cos I initially thought it was... I thought the sentence meant Tさんがヤキモチ焼いたらどんな感じですか？ / ヤキモチを焼いてるTさんってどんな感じですか？)

Comment: @Chocolate "it" is dummy/hypothetical subject. I think he is asking "What is it like to be X?  There is the abstract concept of being X. If you apply it to you, how do you feel it?" In this case, "What is it like to be Jealous?  There is the abstract concept of being Jealous. If you apply it to T-san, how does T-san feel it?"

Comment: ^ あの・・仮主語"it" は "is" の主語ですよね。。。私が言ってるのは、"be jealous" の主語が "T-san"ではないんですか、ってことです。不定詞の意味上の主語は、 for~~ で表して前置するでしょう？ It was a mistake *for* her *to* follow his advice「彼女が彼の忠告に従ったのは間違いでした」、 It is desirable *for* there *to* be a cold season once a year 「年に一度寒い季節があるということは望ましい」(=It is desirable that there should be a cold season once a year)  みたいな。。。ここではそれが当てはまらないとしたら、何故でしょう・・・

Comment: @ Chocolate Thanks for the kind examples. In textbook in Japan, possibly yes. But, I think that "is" is an impersonal verb. So no subject in the sentence in particular. According to Wikipedia: "In linguistics, an impersonal verb is one that has no determinate subject. For example, in the sentence "It rains", rain is an impersonal verb and the pronoun it does not refer to anything." But Wikipedia might be wrong, in such case you are correct.

Comment: あのぅ・・・ 私は、「形式主語の it」の話をしているのではないのですが。。。　**to不定詞の意味上の主語** （つまり、to-infinitiveの動作主）の話をしているのですけど。。。　「What is it like for T-san to be jealous?」で、「for T-san」は「Tさん**にとって** (どんな感じ？)」になるんでしょうか、それとも「Tさん**が** (jealousになる...)」になるんでしょうか？それはどこで判断したらいいんでしょう？

Comment: @ Chocolate Thanks for the comment. Let me state in English a little bit more. I refrain from using "意味上の主語”. This time, "what is it like to be X?" is the main concept. "What is it like to be an actor" then you can ask "for who?" Then, they might reply "for you" or "for Emily" or someone else. So, I guess it's easier to bring up the concept at first. Then let's have a link to the concept and someone. This time, "to be" works as a reference to an adjective word. It's not a reference to actions.

Comment: @Chocoloate So, let's bring the concept of "what it is like to be X" at first. Then you apply it to anyone. And you can ask "how do you feel it?" You might have a couple of interpretations. You are already in a state of X or You imagine that being in a state of X.

Comment: @Chocolate 日本語: 今回は "What is it like to be X？" にfor you を適用した疑問文なので、あなたにとって、X でいるということはどういうことでしょうか？という話だと思います。意味があまりはっきりしないので、意味上の主語という文法上の用語を使うと話が分かりづらいのではないかなと。意味上の主語がまず始めに何かをする訳ではないので、仮主語 it  が Χ という特質を保有していて、"What is" を用いて it に 質問をさせてもらうと、それを"for you" に適用させてもらうという進め方です。

Comment: 「今回は "What is it like to be X？" にfor you を適用した疑問文なので」と断言できるそもそもの理由がわからないんです・・・すみません。

Comment: @Chocolate 断言するような意図はありませんでしたが誤解があったようなので失礼いたしました。Line4: の後半の”それを" for you" に適用させてもらう”と同じニュアンスです。

Answer (score 1):

I think.

"What is it like for T-san to be jealous?"

**ヤキモチ焼くって、Tさんにとってどんな感じですか？**

Edit 1:

So, did I make a mistake in English Grammar.

What is it like (for you) to be a philosopher?

**哲学者でいるって、あなたにとってどんな感じですか？**

http://www.whatisitliketobeaphilosopher.com/

You can find a lot of interviews of philosophers on the page like the following questions about their personalities.

Where did you grow up?

What did your parents do?

Was your family, were you, religious?

and so on so forth...